# Can Zxing read barcode starting with 0?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, barcode, zxing

I integrated ZXing to a Xamarin.Forms project which enables user to scan barcode and put the received data into an Entry field. I tried it with 13-digit barcode and it always fails reading the first number "0" and receives the remaining 12 digits.

Barcodes start with other numbers work fine. I am now band-aiding the code by only accepting 13-digit number but that's not a "solution".

```
using ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;

async void ScanButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs s)
{
    var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage()
    await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);

    scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
    {
        scanPage.IsScanning = false;
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            if (result != null && result.length == 13) // this is just a band-aid...
            {
                entry.text = result.Text;
            }
        });
    };
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the standard of the barcode EAN-13, UPC-A you are trying to get the app to read?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! The standard is EAN-13.

Comment: The answer below if why I asked the question :)

Comment: I've finally resolved it thanks to the comments. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UPC-A is a subset of EAN-13, any EAN-13 start with 0 will be regarded as UPC-A, which is 12 digits without the leading 0.An EAN with a leading 0 is identical to a UPC code without that 0. It is returned as UPC. If you want the response to only be EAN-13 interpretations, set that as the only requested format like this:

```
var opts = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
    {
      PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.EAN_13 }
    };
```